# Upgrade SonarQube and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sonarqube

I am working with SonarQube 6.4.0.25310 Community Edition and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I want to upgrade it to the latest available SonarQube (7.2.1 Community Edition) and MS SQL Server 2016.

I know I have to do it like follow 6.4 -> 6.7.x -> 7.2.1.

What about the upgrade for the whole package: SQL Server + SonarQube?

Can anyone help me with the complete procedure?

THanks

Comment: SQL Server 2012 is not supported anymore. See the [Requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) page. So upgrade the database first before upgrading SonarQube.

Comment: i know it's not supported. I've check thanks. I'd just like to know the procedure... Thanks